# Concatenating Dictionaries gives wrong output

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I just started learning Python and I'm trying to concatenate dictionaries using this code:

```
dict1= {1: 10, 2: 203, 3: 1456}
dict2 = {1: 34, 2: 2034, 3: 176}
dict3 = {1: 134, 2: 2340, 3: 126}
finaldict = {**dict1,**dict2,**dict3}
print(finaldict)
```

but it is printing only `{1: 134, 2: 2340, 3: 126}`

What is wrong with this?

Comment: you cannot have duplicate keys in dictionaries. How do you want your result to look like?

Comment: The values of the last dictionary added replace all others. What is the "right" output according to you?

Comment: The only thing wrong here is your expectation (whatever that is).

Comment: 1st probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011756/is-there-any-pythonic-way-to-combine-two-dicts-adding-values-for-keys-that-appe 2nd probable dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26910708/merging-dictionary-value-lists-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys, therefore, the values of the third dictionary replace / overwrite the other values because they're evaluated from left to right, starting from `dict1`, then `dict2` and `dict3`.

If you dictionaries would be, for example:

```
dict1= {9: 10, 8: 203, 7: 1456}
dict2 = {6: 34, 5: 2034, 4: 176}
dict3 = {3: 134, 2: 2340, 1: 126}
```

The output would be:

```
{9: 10, 8: 203, 7: 1456, 6: 34, 5: 2034, 4: 176, 3: 134, 2: 2340, 1: 126}
```

But since the keys of all the dictionaries are identical, they are just replaced by the new value.

---

For this case, I would use an array of **[`tuples`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm)** (key-value pairs) to handle this better, avoiding overwriting:

```
dict1= {1: 10, 2: 203, 3: 1456}
dict2 = {1: 34, 2: 2034, 3: 176}
dict3 = {1: 134, 2: 2340, 3: 126}
finalDict = list(dict1.items()) + list(dict2.items()) + list(dict3.items())
print(finalDict)
```

**Output:**

```
[(1, 10), (2, 203), (3, 1456), (1, 34), (2, 2034), (3, 176), (1, 134), (2, 2340), (3, 126)]
```

---

Another alternative is to use a dictionary comprehension to form a list of values for each key, as follows:

```
dict1 = {1: 10, 2: 203, 3: 1456}
dict2 = {1: 34, 2: 2034, 3: 176}
dict3 = {1: 134, 2: 2340, 3: 126}
newDict = {key: [value, dict2[key], dict3[key]] for key, value in dict1.items()}
print(newDict)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [10, 34, 134], 2: [203, 2034, 2340], 3: [1456, 176, 126]}
```

Answer (score 3):

The keys `1`, `2`, and `3` are only allowed once per dictionary.  The dictionary construction:

```
finaldict = {**dict1,**dict2,**dict3}
```

Adds the keys and values to `finaldict` from left to right.  So it starts with `dict1` and has the keys and values of

```
finaldict = {1: 10, 2: 203, 3: 1456}
```

Now it moves on `dict2`, which has values for `1`, `2`, and `3` as well, thereby overwriting `10`, `203`, and `1456` with the values `34`, `2034`, and `176` respectively.  And similarly for when it ingests `dict3`.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong, the last added values will replace other values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't concatenate two or more dictionaries with duplicated keys.
If you don't want to change your key names, you should append them in a list

```
dict_list = []
dict_list.append(dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the offchance that what you expected was that the values of the duplicate keys would be summed, here is a way to do that

```
finaldict = {}
for d in (dict1,dict2,dict3):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if k in finaldict:
            finaldict[k] += v
        else:
            finaldict[k] = v
```

There's a directory-like `Counter()` object in `collections` which lets you use `+=` even on a non-existent key. I'll let you look that up when you are ready.