# Merge two dicts by same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following two toy dicts

```
d1 = {
 'a': [2,4,5,6,8,10],
 'b': [1,2,5,6,9,12],
 'c': [0,4,5,8,10,21]
 }
d2 = {
 'a': [12,15],
 'b': [14,16],
 'c': [23,35]
  }
```

and I would like get a unique dictionary where I stack the second dictionary values after the first ones, within the same square brackets.

I tried the following code

```
d_comb = {key:[d1[key], d2[key]] for key in d1}
```

but the output I obtain has two lists within a list for each key, i.e.

```
{'a': [[2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10], [12, 15]],
 'b': [[1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 12], [14, 16]],
 'c': [[0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 21], [23, 35]]}
```

whereas I would like to obtain

```
{'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
 'b': [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 16],
 'c': [0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 21, 23, 35]}
```

How can I do that with a line or two of code?

Comment: Are we sure that both `d1` and `d2` have same set of keys?

Comment: In this example and according to my present needs, yes. 
Of course I'm sure that with different sets of keys in the two dictionaries the code will be different.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You almost had it, instead use `+` to append both lists:

```
{key: d1[key] + d2[key] for key in d1}

{'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
 'b': [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 16],
 'c': [0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 21, 23, 35]}
```

Comment: Damn, it was the plus sign, not the comma.. I knew it was easy but it didn't come to mind! Thanks

Answer (score 14):

if not all the keys from `d2` are in `d1`, then the simplest thing is using set union and `dict.get`:

```
combined_keys = d1.keys() | d2.keys()
d_comb = {key: d1.get(key, []) + d2.get(key, []) for key in combined_keys}
```

Answer (score 10):

You could use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
d1 = {
 'a': [2,4,5,6,8,10],
 'b': [1,2,5,6,9,12],
 'c': [0,4,5,8,10,21]
 }
d2 = {
 'a': [12,15],
 'b': [14,16],
 'c': [23,35]
  }

d_comb = {key:[*d1[key], *d2[key]] for key in d1}

print(d_comb)
```

**Output**

```
{'c': [0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 21, 23, 35], 'b': [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 16], 'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15]}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to efficiently construct a single list from input lists:

```
from itertools import chain
d_comb = {key: list(chain(d1[key], d2[key])) for key in d1}
```

For the more general case covering an arbitrary number of dictionaries and keys which are not equal across dictionaries, see [Merging dictionary value lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54108746/9209546).

Answer (score 4):

The code will work irrespective of whether `d1` or `d2` have the same set of keys. I have added a key `'e'` in `d1` and `'d'` in `d2`.

```
d1 = {'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10], 'b': [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 12], 'c': [0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 21], 'e':[0,0,0]}
d2 = {'a': [12, 15], 'b': [14, 16], 'c': [23, 35], 'd': [13, 3]}

d2_keys_not_in_d1 = d2.keys() - d1.keys()
d1_keys_not_in_d2 = d1.keys() - d2.keys()
common_keys = d2.keys() & d1.keys()

for i in common_keys:
    d[i]=d1[i]+d2[i]
for i in d1_keys_not_in_d2:
    d[i]=d1[i]
for i in d2_keys_not_in_d1:
    d[i]=d2[i]
d
{'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12, 15],
 'b': [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 12, 14, 16],
 'c': [0, 4, 5, 8, 10, 21, 23, 35],
 'd': [13, 3],
 'e': [0, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: this fails if there are keys in `d1` that are not in `d2`, and `d2_keys_not_in_d1 ` can be expressed simpler as `d2.keys() - d1.keys()`

Comment: Thanks Maarten for your feedback. Very appreciated. I have changed the code accordingly and used your expression, which was lot more succinct never the less.

Comment: the common keys can be expressed as ` d2.keys() & d1.keys()`

Comment: Thanks a lot Maarten. Very helpful. I have learnt something :)