# Merge value lists of two dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have several dictionary with equal keys. The values of the key are list. Now I would merge the values lists like.

Input, e.g.:

```
dict_1 ={"a":["1"], "b":["3"]}
dict_2 = {"a":["2"], "b":["3"]}
```

Required output:

```
new_dict = {'a':["1","2"], 'b':["3","3"]}
```

What is the fastest, pythonic way to get this result?

I found this, but this doesn’t fulfill my needs:

```
merged_dic = {**dict_1, **dict_2}
```

and others, but nothing solve my wish.
Is there a built in function without loop over each element, because I have a lot of dictionaries and more complex as my example above?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is exactly the answer you want: [`{ key: dict_1[key] + dict_2[key] for key in dict_1 }`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54109210/3717691)

Comment: @Jeppe If that's the answer why did you post it as a comment?

Comment: @CtrlZ Because it is an answer (its a link) in a different post (this question is a duplicate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(list)
for d in [dict_1, dict_2]:
    for key, value in d.items():
        new_dict[key].extend(value)
```

Comment: if you want, you can add `new_dict = dict(new_dict)` just so the result is a `dict` and not `defaultdict`

Comment: Can also just use `setdefault` to avoid the import and the creation of a new dict in the end

Comment: @DeepSpace, I don’t understood what you mean, sorry..  But sounds shorter.

Comment: We can create `new_dict` as a normal dict, then`new_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)`

Answer (score 1):

Given that your dictionaries have the same keys, you can use **Counter** from **Collections**

```
from collections import Counter

dict_1 = {"a": ["1"], "b": ["3"]}
dict_2 = {"a": ["2"], "b": ["3"]}

# Use Counter to merge the dictionaries
new_dict = Counter(dict_1)
new_dict.update(dict_2)

# Convert the Counter back to a dictionary
new_dict = dict(new_dict)
```

Or/ If else write your own function

```
dict_1 = {"a": ["1"], "b": ["3"]}
dict_2 = {"a": ["2"], "b": ["3"]}

new_dict = {}

# Iterate over the keys of both dictionaries
for key in set(dict_1.keys()) | set(dict_2.keys()):
    # Merge the lists if the key is present in both dictionaries
    new_dict[key] = dict_1.get(key, []) + dict_2.get(key, [])
```

Comment: What benefit does the usage of `Counter` bring to the table? It just adds complexity and overhead as the purpose of the code is **not** to count the elements

Comment: The intuition behind was to get all the elements in order to be able to update them, indirectly `Counter` permits to do this. But yes, maybe it isn't the most optimal way to do the task, as it **counts** indeed before hand, and it can take some time depending on the size of the dictionary.

Comment: It counts? What, how, where?